# can grass modules work separately

Tags: grass-gis, compilation

Grass is very useful tool for pre processing of imagery. I want to use the `i.atcorr` module separately. Will it be possible? I have compiled using `.cpp` files (`AerosolConcentration.cpp`, `AerosolModel.cpp`, `Altitude.cpp`, `AtmosModel.cpp`, etc) given but its asking grass functions to be declared. I dont want to use entire grass, only `i.atcorr` is required. How can i build that single module? Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use GRASS GIS completely in a batch job. See

http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly

It is possible to launch your i.atcorr job via shell script as well as via Python.
Essentially just some environmental variables need to be declared.

Comment: for this grass needs to be installed.but i dont want to install and use just the modules. is it possible.

Comment: Yes. The modules + libraries are GRASS GIS! :-) It is modular. So you can just extract the package and use the i.atcorr binary and the following libraries: libgrass_raster, libgrass_gis, libgrass_btree2, libgrass_datetime since i.atcorr depends on that and the start script. That reduces it to 2MB or so (at least that's the size on my Linux box).

Comment: may i know where should i copy the libraries? in c:/osgeo4w?directly can i create project in visualstudio and use the binaries or through msys i have to do.

Comment: I would not copy them but rather tell visualstudio the path to the libraries...